# Creating a 'for' loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to do an activity in my uni work and am having trouble getting the for loop to work. I have done the first stage using a while loop but I am getting stuck on the second stage. 
My while loop -

```
var i=1;

while (i<=32) {
    i = i*2;
    document.writeln(+i +' ');
}

alert ('Wah-Lah!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second part could be like that:

```
var sum = 0;
var k=1;

// 65 is too big !
for (i=1; i<30; i++) 
   {
   sum += k;
   k*=2;
   document.writeln(+k +' ');
   alert('Sum of all numbers = '+ sum);
   document.writeln(' = ' + sum);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output the sum only, then you can just put the two lines, alert and doc.write outside the for loop

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum = 0;

for (i=1; i<=64; i*=2) {
    sum += i;
    document.writeln(i);
}

document.writeln('sum: ' + sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code the following way :

```
var sum=0;
for (i=1; i<65; i=i*2) {
    sum += i;
    document.writeln('' + i); //Displays values 1 2 4 8...       
}
```

//Display Sum outside loop

```
document.writeln(' = ' + sum);
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if I understand you well but in your for loop you are increasing you counter by 1, so in output you will get 1,2,3...,64. If you want to get output as 1,2,4,8... change your step argument to: i = i + 2. Finally your for loop should looks like:

```
for(i = 1; i < 65; i + 2)
```

Comment: `(i + 2)` does not change `i`. This results in an endless loop.

Comment: Ups... my mistake there should be i+=2

Comment: That would change `i`, but it still wouldn't be correct.